# How can I continue processing a record, even if it doesn't exist in table B?

Tags: sql, teradata

Probably a dumb question but will provide a basic example for representation. I have 2 tables and a query with conditional statements. Table A is the primary (if you will) and if account exists in Table B, that would be a plus. If not, return null. Right now, it only returns the record if account exists in A and B. Example:

```
SELECT
A.id_nbr AS ID,
A.contact_type AS contype,
A.last_update AS date,
B.card_type as card_type
FROM id_info A,
     billing_info B
WHERE (A.contact_type = 'AAA' OR A.contact_type = 'BBB' OR A.contact_type = 'CCC')
AND A.id_nbr = B.id_nbr;
```

If record exists, great:

```
ID          contype     date         card_type
111111111   AAA         2020-02-21   MS
```

If not, great too:

```
ID          contype     date         card_type
222222222   AAA         2020-02-21   null
```

Basically, I don't want to negate the entire record if it doesn't exist in table B.
Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use left join

```
SELECT
A.id_nbr AS ID,
A.contact_type AS contype,
A.last_update AS date,
B.card_type as card_type
FROM id_info A
LEFT JOIN billing_info B ON  (A.contact_type = 'AAA' OR A.contact_type = 'BBB' OR A.contact_type = 'CCC')
    AND A.id_nbr = B.id_nbr;
```

You need an outer join and for this you can use the explicit join syntax  and left join.

Answer (score 1):

This is the case to use a `LEFT` join from `id_info` to `billing_info` based on the equality of the columns `id_nbr` in both tables, but the other conditions must be set in the `WHERE` clause if you want results only for these 3 types and instead of `OR`s it's simpler to use the `IN` operator:

```
SELECT
  A.id_nbr AS ID,
  A.contact_type AS contype,
  A.last_update AS date,
  B.card_type as card_type
FROM id_info A LEFT JOIN billing_info B
ON AND A.id_nbr = B.id_nbr
WHERE A.contact_type IN ('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC')
```